# repopulating multiple select form with a drop down form through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

i want to repopulate a multiple select form from the database with ajax by just selecting a drop down value.

here is the code for the drop down menu:

```
    <?php 
    $sql2 = "select _id, title from sub_category order by title;";
    $sel2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);
    $array2 = array();
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel2)){
      $array2[] = $row2;
    }
    ?>

       <div class="span2">
            <select name="des_pos" id="des_pos">
               <?php
                  foreach($array2 as $value2){ ?>

                  <option value ="<?php echo $value2['_id']; ?>" <?php if($value2["title"] == $desired_position){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>><?php echo $value2['title']; ?> </option>

                  <?php

                  }
                  ?>
            </select>
        </div>
```

and here is the code for the multiple select form:

```
$sql4 = "SELECT _id, score_type from test_category where sub_code='$des_pos_id'";

  $sel4 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql4);

  $array4 = array();

  while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel4)){

      $array4[] = $row4;

  }

            <select name = 'test_tags[]' multiple>
            <?php

            foreach($array4 as $value4){ ?>

            <option value ="<?php echo $value4['_id']; ?>" <?php echo in_array($value4['_id'], $test_tag) ? 'selected="true"' : null; ?>><?php echo $value4['score_type']; ?></option>

            <?php

            }
            ?>
            </select>
```

so the the output that i want is, the values of the multiple select form should change depending on the choice on the dropdown menu...

i need a jquery.ajax code for this but i don't know where to begin... i am getting the value through a $_POST.. but i want to do it without going through another page and redirecting.

Comment: whats is your problem?

Comment: i need a jquery.ajax code for this but i don't know where to begin... i am getting the value through a $_POST.. but i want to do it without going through another page and redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

some helpful stuff:
AJAX Tutorial: [W3schools ajax tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP)

then you need to learn about [HTML DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

and then you need to learn about [Select DOM Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp)

mixing those will teach you how to figure out your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the first dropdown `#des_pos` select event send the ajax post to the php page as follow.

```
 $("#des_pos").select(function(e){
 $.ajax({
   url:"getdropdata.php",
   dataType:"json",
   success: function(data){
     $.each(data,function(index,value){
      $("#multiselect").append("<option value="+value+">"+value+"</option>"));
  });
 }
})
});
```